# Combinatorial optimization - blocks & subsets

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

> Given a set of size $25$, what is the minimum number of subsets of size $5$ such that all subsets of size $3$ are encompassed?

Comment: You should add an example.

Answer (score 0):

Each 5-subset covers at most $\binom{5}{3}=10$ 3-subsets, so you need at least $\binom{25}{3}/10=2300/10=230$ 5-subsets.  Bounds $[240,256]$ are given in the [La Jolla Covering Repository](https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/cover/show_cover.php?v=25&k=5&t=3).

Comment: Why the downvote? The minimum is not known, but I provided what are presumably the best known bounds, as well as a link to a solution that attains the upper bound.